# Как сделать так чтобы можно было передвигаться не только вниз, вправо но и вверх. налево

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#items-container');

let startY;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
let scrollTop;
let isDown;

container.addEventListener('mousedown', e => mouseIsDown(e));
container.addEventListener('mouseup', e => mouseUp(e))
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => mouseLeave(e));
container.addEventListener('mousemove', e => mouseMove(e));

function mouseIsDown(e) {
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
  startX = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = container.scrollLeft;
  scrollTop = container.scrollTop;
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  isDown = false;
}

function mouseLeave(e) {
  isDown = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;
    const walkY = y - startY;
    container.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;

    const x = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
    const walkX = x - startX;
    container.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walkX;

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.container {
  background: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.react-flow__background {
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 1000px
}

.item {
  width: 90%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #30a57f;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #c17a38;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="items-container">
  <svg class="react-flow__background react-flow__container">
            <pattern id="pattern-84426" x="-3" y="-4" width="18" height="18" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <circle cx="0.45" cy="0.45" r="0.45" fill="#81818a"></circle>
            </pattern>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-84426)"></rect>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Визуально все передвигается

Comment: Забыл добавить, он передвигается тогда, когда ты уже сдвинул не много вправо, а если сразу нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
    
    const layerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    offset: {
      x: 0.0,
      y: 0.0
    },
    zoom: 1
  });

    // ...

useEffect(() => {
    if (!layerRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    layerRef.current.onwheel = (e: WheelEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        const speedFactor =
          (e.deltaMode === 1 ? 0.05 : e.deltaMode ? 1 : 0.002) * 10;

        setViewport((prev) => {
          const pinchDelta = -e.deltaY * speedFactor;

          return {
            ...prev,
            zoom: Math.min(
              1.3,
              Math.max(0.1, prev.zoom * Math.pow(2, pinchDelta))
            )
          };
        });
      }
    };
  }, [setViewport]);

  return (
    <div
      className="app"
      ref={layerRef}
      // ...
    >
      <div className="container">
        <div
          className="nodes-container"
          style={{
            transform: `
              translate(
                ${viewport.offset.x * viewport.zoom}px, 
                ${viewport.offset.y * viewport.zoom}px
              ) 
              scale(${viewport.zoom})
            `
          }}
        >
          {/* ... */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```